# Extract end position from CIGAR

Tags: r, sequence-alignment, sam, cigar

I was wondering how could I obtain the end position of an alignment using its start position and its CIGAR String.

If an alignment present some soft clipping, for example:

```
    20S55M
```

Then, would the start position indicated in the SAM file be the first soft clipped base, or the first correctly mapped base?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The start position is the first correctly mapped base. One way to do it, is to use GenomicAlignments in R to read in the alignments.

For example the sam file looks like this:

```
cat test.sam 
@HD VN:1.3  SO:coordinate
@SQ SN:chrI LN:228861
D00689:415:CD4LUANXX:3:1316:7447:98083#CGGCTATGCAGGACGT 0   chrI    769 0   42M8S   *   0   0   CCATAGCCCGGTGGGGCCTGTGCTGCCACAGAGGGTGTGTCTAGATCGGA  B/B//FFFFFFBFFFF//7FF/<F/FFBFFFF//<F///<F/BFB//<F/  NM:i:1  MD:Z:21A20  AS:i:37 XS:i:37
D00689:415:CD4LUANXX:3:2308:9597:30445#CGGCTATGCAGGACGT 0   chrI    3965    0   3S47M   *   0   0   CCACACACCCACACACCACACCCACACCACACCCACACCACACCCACACC  BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFBF<FFFFF<FF  NM:i:0  MD:Z:47 AS:i:47 XS:i:47
```

We convert to bam:

```
samtools view -bS test.sam > test.bam
```

And read using R:

```
library(GenomicAlignments)
gr = readGAlignments("test.bam")
gr

GAlignments object with 2 alignments and 0 metadata columns:
      seqnames strand       cigar    qwidth     start       end     width
         <Rle>  <Rle> <character> <integer> <integer> <integer> <integer>
  [1]     chrI      +       42M8S        50       769       810        42
  [2]     chrI      +       3S47M        50      3965      4011        47
          njunc
      <integer>
  [1]         0
  [2]         0
  -------
  seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome
```

The start and the end can be retrieved using:

```
start(gr)
[1]  769 3965
end(gr)
[1]  810 4011
```

Answer (score 2):

The match is starting with the first mapped base ignoring any softclipped parts of the read.

As an example this are two reads from a bam file of mine:

```
start   cigar   sequence 
11710   17S83M  NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGGCCTGGCCATGTGTATTTTTTTAAATTTCCACTGATGATTTTGCTGCATGGCCGGTGTTGAGAATGACTGCGCAAATTTGCC   
11713   100M    CTGGCCATGTGTATTTTTTTAAATTTCCACTGATGATTTTGCTGCATGGCCGGTGTTGAGAATGACTGCGCAAATTTGCCGGATTTCCTTTGCTGTTCCT
```